# How to remove the spacing in the itemize function in a table

Tags: latex

I am trying to use the following code in the table using latex

```
\begin{table}[htb!]
\caption {Table}
\begin{center}
\small\setlength\tabcolsep{5.2pt} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.005} 
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.14\textwidth}|p{0.14\textwidth}|p{0.14\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{Text}& \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text}\\
\hline
Text & \begin{itemize} \item{Text} \item {Text} \item \end{itemize} & Text \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

1. How to make the Text using the itemize to align to the left and remove the spacing between each bullet points as shown in the photo
2. How to remove or decrease the row spacing in the table

[image]

Comment: [TeX-LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should align the itemize text to the left and remove the spacing between bullet points:

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
\item Text
\item Text
\end{itemize}
```

To decrease the row spacing in the table, you can use the following command in the preamble:

`\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}`

Or you can adjust the number in the argument to set the desired row spacing.

Comment: How to align it to the left corner of the table

Comment: you can use a combination of the flushleft environment and the tabular environment.
```\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item First item
      \item Second item
    \end{itemize}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{tabular}
```
In this example, the p{5cm} argument in the tabular environment specifies the width of the first column to be 5 centimeters. You can adjust this value as needed to control the width of the table. The flushleft environment is used to align the text to the left of the column.

Comment: it is not working is there a way of doing it with the first code as the first did remove the spacing between item but didnot align it to the left as shown in the photo

Comment: i'll modify my replay with the solution .

Comment: Thank you so much it did work with the modified code. But the row spacing is not decreasing and there is still white space. I decrease the spacing up to 0.005 and it is still not decreased any thoughts.

Comment: If decreasing the row spacing using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.005} `doesn't seem to work, you can try using the `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}` command to decrease the row spacing. If that still doesn't work, you can try changing the font size of the text within the table to a smaller font, or try manually adjusting the spacing between the rows by using negative values in the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{}` command. Additionally, to align the items in the itemize environment to the left, you can wrap the itemize environment within a flushleft environment, like this:

Comment: \begin{flushleft}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Text}
\item{Text}
\item{Text}
\end{itemize}
\end{flushleft}

Answer (score 1):

You need to load [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to gain access to addition options. Then, either apply settings in-place for a specific list or clone `itemize` with additional settings.

In settings, you have to negate vertical spacing added by environments. But then, this messes up with the lists which you want to mix with a regular texts. So, one workaround is to clone itemize into two separate lists you use with or without surrounding text--you can still apply global settings common for two lists. Here's an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\newlist{soloitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize,soloitemize]{
  nosep, nolistsep,
  topsep=6pt,
  align=left,
  left=0pt,
  label=$\bullet$,
}
\setlist*[soloitemize]{
  before=\vspace{\dimexpr-6pt-\topsep},
  after=\vspace{-10pt},
}

\begin{document}
Regular text with a regular itemize:
\begin{itemize}
\item Text
\item Text
\item X
\end{itemize}
        
\begin{table}[htb!]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \caption {Table with custom itemize}
  \begin{center}
    \small\setlength\tabcolsep{5.2pt} 
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.14\textwidth}|p{0.14\textwidth}|p{0.14\textwidth}|}
      \hline
      \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text}\\
      \hline
      Text & \begin{soloitemize}
             \item Text
             \item Text
             \item Text
             \item Text
             \item X
             \end{soloitemize} & Text text
                                 \begin{tabitemize}
                                 \item Text
                                 \item X
                                 \end{tabitemize}
                                 Text \\
      \hline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab1}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

Regular text.
\end{document}
```

[image]